# Complex solutions to trig functions

Tags: complex-analysis

We consider: $$2\sin{z} + \cos{z} = i\sin{z}$$ Where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We are to prove the solutions are given by $$z = \left(n\pi - \frac{\pi}{8}\right) - \frac{1}{4}i\ln{2}$$ For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ My attempts have led to $$ z = \arctan\left({\frac{-1}{2-i}}\right)$$ and also, by squaring the equation: $$ \sin\left({2z-\frac{\pi}{4}}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}$$ Which I doubt is valid (though I don't know if the complex argument to a sine function can yield a value $>1$).

None of which give a simple route to the required result. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid squaring wherever applicable, as it immediately introduces extraneous roots.

$$\cos z=(i-2)\sin z$$

$$\iff\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}(i-2)$$

$$\iff\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}=\frac{i-2}i$$

Apply [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo) to find $e^{2iz}=\dfrac{e^{iz}}{e^{-iz}}=\cdots$

Hope you can take it from here

Comment: Fantastic! Got the required result. Many thanks for your help. A neat trick too, will come in handy in the future no doubt!